# Spivak, Ch. 22, "Infinite Sequences", Problem 1(iii): How do we show $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left [\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n+1}\right ]=0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The following is a problem from Chapter 22 "Infinite Sequences" from Spivak's *Calculus*

> 1. Verify the following limits
>
> (iii) $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left
>  [\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n+1}\right ]=0$

The solution manual says

> $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left [\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n+1}\right
>  ]$$
>
> $$=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left [\left
>  (\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[8]{n^2}\right )+\left
>  (\sqrt[4]{n}-\sqrt[4]{n+1}\right )\right ]$$
>
> $$=0+0=0$$
>
> (Each of these two limits can be proved in the same way that
> $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})=0$ was proved in the
> text)

How do we show $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left [\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[8]{n^2}\right ]=0$?

Note that in the main text, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})=0$ was solved by multiplying and dividing by $(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})$ to reach

$$0<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}<\epsilon$$

$$\implies n>\frac{1}{4\epsilon^2}$$

Comment: Why would you need to prove $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left [\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n^2}\right ]=0$? Note that $\sqrt[8]{n^2} = \sqrt[4]{n}$.

Comment: Limit is $-\infty$.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+%28n%5E2%2B1%29%5E%281%2F8%29-%28n%5E2%29%5E%281%2F4%29

Comment: To all that have submitted comments, I apologize for the typos in the original post. They are corrected now.

Answer (score 4):

The solution considers $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sqrt[8]{n^2+1} - \sqrt[8]{n^2}\right) \tag{1}$$ and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sqrt[4]{n} - \sqrt[4]{n+1}\right), \tag{2}$$ yet you are asking about $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sqrt[8]{n^2+1} - \sqrt[\color{red}{4}]{n^2}\right), \tag{3}$$ which is neither of these.

I will ignore your expression and illustrate how $(1)$ is evaluated in the manner suggested.  Let $a_n = \sqrt[8]{n^2+1}$ and $b_n = \sqrt[8]{n^2}$.  Then because $$(a_n - b_n)(a_n^7 + a_n^6 b_n + a_n^5 b_n^2 + \cdots + a_n^2 b_n^5 + a_n b_n^6 + b_n^7) = a_n^8 - b_n^8, \tag{4}$$ it follows that $$\begin{align}
a_n - b_n 
&= \frac{a_n^8 - b_n^8}{a_n^7 + a_n^6 b_n + a_n^5 b_n^2 + \cdots + a_n^2 b_n^5 + a_n b_n^6 + b_n^7} \\
&= \frac{1}{a_n^7 + a_n^6 b_n + a_n^5 b_n^2 + \cdots + a_n^2 b_n^5 + a_n b_n^6 + b_n^7}. \tag{5} \end{align}$$  Since both $a_n \to \infty$ and $b_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, the denominator of $(5)$ tends to $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$; hence $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n - b_n = 0$$ as claimed.  The same argument applies to $(2)$.  It does **not** apply to $(3)$.  Why?

Comment: I've probably been studying too long tonight because I had some major typos in my original post and I apologize. You are correct, I am indeed interested in the limit in $(1)$.

Comment: Why would one know about the factorization in $(4)$? Is it a common factorization?

Comment: @evianpring Yes this is a common factorization, typically learned in high school algebra:  for integers $k \ge 2$, $$x^k - y^k = (x-y)(x^{k-1} + x^{k-2} y + \cdots + x y^{k-2} + y^{k-1}).$$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
 \sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n+1}&=\big(n^2+1)^{1/8}-(n+1)^{2/8} \\
&=\big(n^2+1)^{1/8}-(n^2+2n+1)^{1/8}\\
&=\frac{\big(1+\tfrac{1}{n^2}\big)^{1/8}-1-\Big(\big(1+\tfrac{2}{n}+\tfrac{1}{n^2}\big)^{1/8}-1\Big)}{\tfrac{1}{n^{1/4}}}
\end{align}

The function $f(x)=x^{1/8}$, $x>0$ has a finite derivative at $x=1$. Letting $h=\frac{1}{n^2}$, we obtain that
$$\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h^{1/8}}=h^{7/8}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}\xrightarrow{h\rightarrow0}0\cdot f'(1)=0.$$
Similarly, letting $h=\frac{1}{n}$ we obtain
$$\frac{f(x+2h+h^2)-f(1)}{h^{1/4}}=(2h^{3/4}+h^{7/4})\frac{f(1+2h+h^2)-f(1)}{2h+h^2}\xrightarrow{h\rightarrow0}0\cdot f'(1)=0$$

Hence
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow}\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n+1}=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider a different approach as seen by the following.
\begin{align}
\sqrt[m]{n^p + 1} - \sqrt[m]{n^p} &= \sqrt[m]{n^p} \, \left( \sqrt[m]{1 + \frac{1}{n^p}} - 1 \right) \\
&= \sqrt[m]{n^p} \, \left( e^{\frac{1}{m} \, \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^p}\right)} - 1 \right) \\
&= \sqrt[m]{n^p} \, \left( \frac{1}{m} \, \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^p}\right) +  \frac{1}{2 \, m^2} \, \ln^{2}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^p}\right) + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{m^3}\right) \right) \\
&= \sqrt[m]{n^p} \, \frac{1}{m} \, \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^p}\right) \, \left( 1 +  \frac{1}{2 \, m} \, \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^p}\right) + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right) \right)
\end{align}
which gives the limit as
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sqrt[m]{n^p + 1} - \sqrt[m]{n^p} \right) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \, \sqrt[m]{n^p} \, \frac{1}{m} \, \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^p}\right) \, \left( 1 +  \frac{1}{2 \, m} \, \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^p}\right) + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{m} \, \ln(1 + 0) \, \left(1 + \frac{\ln(1)}{2 \, m} + \cdots \right) \times \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \, \sqrt[m]{n^p} \right) \ \\
&= 0.
\end{align}

Now, for the main problem:
\begin{align}
\sqrt[8]{n^2 + 1} - \sqrt[4]{n+1} &= \sqrt[8]{n^2 + 1} - n^{1/4} + n^{1/4} - \sqrt[4]{n+1} \\
&= ( \sqrt[8]{n^2 + 1} - \sqrt[8]{n^2}) - (\sqrt[4]{n+1} - \sqrt[4]{n})
\end{align}
such that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sqrt[8]{n^2 + 1} - \sqrt[4]{n+1} \right) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sqrt[8]{n^2 + 1} - \sqrt[8]{n^2} \right) - \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sqrt[4]{n + 1} - \sqrt[4]{n} \right) \\
&= (0) - (0) = 0.
\end{align}

Comment: I understand every step except the second to last step in the general case. Ie, the calculation of the limit that gives $\ln{(1+0)}\times ...$. What happens to the $\sqrt[m]{n^p}$ term?

Comment: @evianpring   added the missing part. In this case $\ln(1) = 0$ is a leading term and gives the zero result.

Comment: What is a "leading term"? Why don't we have $\frac{1}{m}\cdot 0 \cdot 0 \cdot 0 ... \cdot \infty$ where $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[m]{n^p}=\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

I want to present you a very general method that does not involve any trick. Basically this is using the taylor expansion of $(1+x)^\alpha$ around $0$ to get en equivalent of the sequence :
\begin{aligned}
(1+x)^{\alpha} &=1+\alpha x+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2 !} x^{2}+\cdots+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1) \cdots(\alpha-n+1)}{n !} x^{n}+o\left(x^{n}\right)(x \to 0) \\
\end{aligned}
First let's factorize by the dominant term in each term of the sum :

$$\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n+1}= n^{\frac{1}{4}}(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^\frac18 -n^\frac{1}{4} (1+\frac1n)^\frac14  $$

Then we use the Taylor expansion of $(1+x)^\alpha$ around $0$ at order $1$ :

$$ (1+\frac{1}{n^2})^\frac18 = 1+ o(\frac1{n}) $$
$$ (1+\frac1n)^\frac14  = 1+\frac14\frac1n +  o(\frac1{n})  $$

Therefore

\begin{align}
\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n+1} &= n^{\frac{2}{8}}(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^\frac18 -n^\frac{1}{4} (1+\frac1n)^\frac14  \\
&= n^{\frac{1}{4}}(1+ o(\frac1{n})) - n^\frac{1}{4}(1+\frac14\frac1n +o(\frac1{n})) \\
&= -\frac14 \frac{1}{n^\frac34}+o(\frac{1}{n^\frac34}) \\
&\sim  -\frac14 \frac{1}{n^\frac34}
\end{align}

Conclusion : $$\boxed{\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n+1} \sim -\frac14 \frac{1}{n^\frac34} }$$

Since $ -\frac14 \frac{1}{n^\frac34} \to 0$ then the $\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n+1} \to 0$.

And we have a little bonus, we know that it's approaching $0$ from the negative side since  the equivalent is negative. We also know that it converges towards $0$ with a a certain speed given by the equivalent.

Comment: About which point is the Taylor polynomial in $ (1+\frac{1}{n^2})^\frac18 = 1+ o(\frac1{n}) $ being computed?

Comment: I'm expanding at $0$ since $\frac1n \to 0$ when $n \to +\infty$. You can replace $x$ by $\frac1n$ in the formula above. I also used the implicit fact that $\frac1{n^2} =  o(\frac1n)$.

Comment: How can we compute the Taylor polynomial of $(1+\frac{1}{n})^p$ about $0$ if this function isn't defined at $0$?

Comment: The variable is $\frac1n$ not $n$. The taylor expansion of $(1+x)^p$ is valid for x close to $0$ and thus it's valid for $n$ going to infinity. As a sanity check you can verify that $n^\frac34 (\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n+1}) \to - \frac14$ by looking at large values of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Although *heropup* has a pretty solution, given the author's comments, I am  pretty certain that Spivak intended the reader to proceed as follows:

As the solution manual states:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n+1}= \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[8]{n^2}+\sqrt[4]{n}-\sqrt[4]{n+1}$$

To show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[8]{n^2}=0$, we can take Spivak's suggestion...*but we need to apply it multiple times*.

Observe:

\begin{align}&\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[8]{n^2}\times\left(\frac{\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[8]{n^2}}{\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[8]{n^2}}\right)=\frac{\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n^2}}{\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[8]{n^2}}\implies \\
&\frac{\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}-\sqrt[4]{n^2}}{\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[8]{n^2}}\times\left(\frac{\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[4]{n^2}}{\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[4]{n^2}}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{n^2}}{\left(\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[8]{n^2}\right)\times\left(\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[4]{n^2}\right)} \implies\\
&\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-\sqrt{n^2}}{\left(\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[8]{n^2}\right)\times\left(\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[4]{n^2}\right)}\times\left(\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{n^2}}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{n^2}}\right)\\
&=\frac{n^2+1-n}{\left(\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[8]{n^2}\right)\times\left(\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[4]{n^2}\right)\times\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{n^2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[8]{n^2}\right)\times\left(\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[4]{n^2}\right)\times\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{n^2}\right)}\end{align}

And, certainly, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt[8]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[8]{n^2}\right)\times\left(\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}+\sqrt[4]{n^2}\right)\times\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}+\sqrt{n^2}\right)}=0$$

A similar argument applies for: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[4]{n}-\sqrt[4]{n+1}$...although, we'll have $\frac{-1}{\infty}$, which still, nonetheless, equals $0$.